# Get first and second element satisfying a CSS path

Tags: css, selenium, xpath, path, selector

Let's say I have a CSS path:
`.event__participant.event__participant--away`
How can I get the first element satisfying that path? Or second element? Or X element? I'm using selenium and I don't want to be getting all 100+ of them. `:nth-type-of` doesn't work and I can't use `nth-child` because it has more children than just `.event__participant--away`.

Comment: Try `:nth-of-type` instead of `:nth-type-of`.

Comment: Sorry, meant `:nth-of-type`. I've tried it already. Doesn't work.

Comment: Once again, not `:nth-type-of`, but `:nth-of-type`. See [docs](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors).

Comment: Once again made a mistake on SO, but was trying the right thing in code. It returns 0 elements. Without `:nth-of-type` there is 100+ of them. Full path I was trying: `.event__participant.event__participant--home:nth-of-type(1)`

Comment: OK, how would I know if you have written it right in your code if you mistyped it twice here? Also it would be great if you have posted your code here, just in case.

Comment: `Driver.FindElementsByCssSelector(".event__participant.event__participant--home:nth-of-type(1)")`

Comment: Find a better locator that only returns the one you want. We can't do that with no HTML posted. You should post the code you are actually using and fix your typo mentioned in the comments. Don't post updates or relevant info in the comments, instead update your question to include all the important stuff so future readers don't have to read all your comments to get everything they need to understand and answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the css provided at the top in your original post the css in your script should be

```
Driver.FindElementsByCssSelector(".event__participant.event__participant--home:nth-of-type(1)")
```

Comment: Make sure the class names match between the application and selenium script.